# using ORDER BY instead of PARTION BY row_number().over()

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

While using `sqlalchemy.func.rownumber().over` its generating **PARTITION BY** how to change it to **ORDER BY**.

```py
query = session.query(
    sqlalchemy.func.row_number().over(Record.id).label('#'),
    Record.id,
    Record.state,
).filter(
    Record.state == "new"
)
```

sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine generates with **PARTITION BY**

```sql
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY records.pk) AS "#", records.pk AS records_pk, records.state AS records_state
FROM records 
WHERE records.state = %(state_1)s
```

Comment: Try `sqlalchemy.func.row_number().over(order_by=Record.id).label('#')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `over()` function should take an `order_by` argument:

```py
query = session.query(
    sqlalchemy.func.row_number().over(order_by=Record.id).label('#')
    Record.id,
    Record.state,
).filter(
    Record.state == "new"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
select records.pk AS records_pk, records.state AS records_state
FROM records 
WHERE records.state = %(state_1)s
Group by records.pk, records.state
order by records.pk, records.state
```

Use group by. GROUP BY clause is aggregate while the PARTITION BY clause is analytic.